# Bidirectional HQL Query with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I'm fairly new to HQL / NHibernate so this may be a bit of an amateurish question. Basically I have a bidirectional many-to-one association. In my query, I am trying to find all of the “parent” entities that contain “children” that match a certain criteria.

I really don’t want to run the first query on the children and then query the parents by a list of IDs as I figure there has *got* to be a better way of doing this.

Thanks

Edit: I can't use a Sproc b/c they apparently don't believe in them here...yes, yes, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like :

```
select p from Parent
join p.Children c
where c.Property = 'some_value'
```

Also have a look at [The NHibernate Query Language](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: Thank you, that certainly helped.